# concepts template argument deduction

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts

The concept below has two template parameters but only one is specified during usage. Is `T` always deduced and `InnerType` always the parameter that needs explicit specification?

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <span>

template < class T, class InnerType >
concept RangeOf = requires(T&& t) 
{
    requires std::same_as<std::remove_cvref_t<decltype(*std::ranges::begin(t))>, InnerType >;
    std::ranges::end(t);
};

void print(const RangeOf<char> auto& seq) {
    std::cout << "char seq: " << std::string_view(seq.data(), seq.size()) << std::endl;
}

int main() {    
    auto a_view = std::string_view("hello");
    print(a_view);
}
```

Comment: Unrelated: If you want a plain `char[]` (which is a valid `RangeOf<char>`) to work in that `print` you could make it `std::cout << "char seq: " << std::string_view(std::begin(seq), std::end(seq)) << std::endl;`

Comment: "*Is T always deduced and InnerType always the parameter that needs explicit specification?*" The short answer is yes.

Comment: The way to define that concept to do that check is `template <class R, class Inner> concept RangeOf = ranges::range<R> && same_as<remove_cvref_t<ranges::range_reference_t<R>>, Inner>;` Use the concepts and type traits that the library has. Also, just because a type is a range of `char` doesn't mean you can construct a `string_view` from it or even that it has a `.size()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use concepts with templates as you did there, the type you are trying to constraint matches the very first type-argument. Everything else you specify comes after that in the order you specified. Here's a simplified example:

```
#include <concepts>

template <class T1, class T2, class T3>
concept ThreeTypes = std::same_as<T1, int> &&
                     std::same_as<T2, short> && 
                     std::same_as<T3, long>;


template <ThreeTypes<short, long> T>
void foo(T t) {

}

int main() {
    foo(14); // OK
    // foo(14.1); // Won't compile
}
```

[See online](https://godbolt.org/z/bKefn5EfP).